# notifyAll() does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

In the following code the notifyAll() is called but does not reactivate the other threads. The output I get is

- beta waiting to get notified at time: 1441870698303, activeWriters: 1
- alpha waiting to get notified at time: 1441870698303, activeWriters: 1
- delta notify all at time: 1441870698403, activeWriters: 0

  public class Waiter implements Runnable{

  ```
      private static int activeWriters;

      public Waiter(Message msg){
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          beforeWrite();
          try {
              Thread.sleep(100);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          afterWrite();
      }

      protected synchronized void beforeWrite(){
          while (activeWriters > 0 ) {
              try {
                  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" waiting to get notified at time: "+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ", activeWriters: " + activeWriters);
                  wait();
                  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" waiting got notified at time: "+System.currentTimeMillis()+ ", activeWriters: " + activeWriters);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          ++activeWriters;
      }
      protected synchronized void afterWrite(){
          --activeWriters;
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" notify all at time: "+System.currentTimeMillis() + ", activeWriters: " + activeWriters);
          notifyAll();
      }

  }

  public class WaitNotifyTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Message msg = new Message("process it");
          Waiter waiter1 = new Waiter(msg);
          Waiter waiter2 = new Waiter(msg);
          Waiter waiter3 = new Waiter(msg);
          new Thread(waiter1,"alpha").start();
          new Thread(waiter2, "beta").start();
          new Thread(waiter3, "delta").start();

      }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls `wait()` and `notify*()` work on a specified object, meaning that `notify*()` wakes up threads which called `wait()` on the same object.

In your case you call `wait()` and `notifyAll()` on 3 different objects which aren't connected, so this can't work.

You can add a static mutex:

```
private static final Object mutex = new Object();
```

and then call `wait()` and `notify*()` on this object. Remeber to synchronize on the mutex first:

```
synchronized (mutex) {
    ...
    mutex.wait();
    ...
}
```

and:

```
synchronized (mutex) {
    ...
    mutex.notifyAll();
    ...
}
```

All access to `activeWriters` must be in these `synchronized` blocks for 2 reasons. Currently access to it is effectively unsynchronized, because you synchronize on 3 different objects. Apart from that `activeWriters` is your condition variable, and you want to `notify*()` other threads that it changed. For this to work the change of the variable and the `notify*()` call must be in the same `synchronized` block.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I see now that there was indeed no link between the 3 threads.
If i understand correctly my method beforeWrite should change to

    protected void beforeWrite(){
     synchronized (mutex) {
  while (activeWriters > 0 ) {
          try {
       mutex.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       }
              }
  ++activeWriters;
     }
    }

Comment: @user3637488 Yes, the same applies for the 2nd method.

Comment: Thx very much this works. 
ps sorry for bad formatting of code in comment :)

Comment: I have done some additional research on concurrency. Is it furthermore correct that the declaration of "activeWriters" in my code should be "private static **volatile** int activeWriters" because multiple threads acces this variable?

Comment: @user3637488 If you always access shared variables from a `synchronized` block, you don't need `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major design flaw in your program.

You are creating 3 separate instances of Waiter class and expect all them to access `activeWriters` in synchronized fashion. This is not possible because instance methods will acquire different locks but modify same static variable `activeWriters`.

To provide static variables concurrent access, you should access them via. synchronized static methods.
One way could be to make `beforeWrite()` and `afterWrite()` methods `static`.